# Cambios de comportamiento según la Marca

Tags: java, android, android-studio, configuración

Muy buenas. Me he encontrado que según la versión de Android, la marca del móvil y el modelo, influyen en el comportamiento de algunas pequeñas acciones.

Por ejemplo, entre algunas cosas que me he encontrado, una importante es que hay un botón situado en el menú que sólo aparece cuando se cumplen una serie de condiciones. El problema es que cuando un usuario utiliza la app y es de marca Samsung, este botón no aparece, y en el resto de dispositivos sí. También sucede con el sistema bluetooth, pero esto es un tema aparte.

¿Este caso del botón cómo lo resolverías?

La versión de appcompat que utilizo es:

> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'

Otra información:

> compileSdkVersion 29 
>   buildToolsVersion '28.0.3' 
>   minSdkVersion 16
>   targetSdkVersion 29 multiDexEnabled true
>
> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1' classpath
>   'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0' classpath
>   'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+' classpath
>   "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.31"

Comment: y ¿que acción realiza el botón que indicas?, recuerda  revisar [ask] con respeto a las preguntas que requieren opiniones, este tipo de preguntas las puedes realizar en el [chat], trata de obtener reputación, saludos.

Comment: El botón realiza un Intent hacia otra actividad y traslada datos de la actual, a la destino. De momento, esto lo he solucionado de forma provisional de otra manera. Me gustaría saber si alguien se ha encontrado con problemas similares y si lo ha podido solucionar.

Answer (score 0):

Durante este tiempo, documentándome con los usuarios que utilizan mis aplicaciones y mirando informes de CrashLytics. He descubierto, que un gran porcentaje de problemas proviene de la capa de Samsung. Para que los programadores podamos lidiar con estos problemas, y bajar drásticamente el índice de excepciones, os recomiendo:
- usar varios móviles de diferentes marcas, sobretodo Samsung. Estaría bien, usar el S4 por ejemplo.
- descargar las imágenes oficiales de la página de Samsung, y realizar pruebas directamente
- usar una característica de FireBase llamada Robo, que analiza la app (cuidado que si tienes que realizar un login, no podrá realizar bien la prueba)